# why the javascript code can't work?

Tags: javascript

the html code:

```
 <div class="fr_search">        
      <select class="search_l" onchange="selectSearch(select)">
        <option value="0">whole site search</option>
         <option value="1">google search</option>
      </select>
    <form action="/"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="search-theme-form">
<input  name="search_theme_form" id="edit-search-theme-form-1" size="15" value=""    class="form-text" />

 。。。。。。
   </form>
</div>
```

the js code:

```
function selectSearch(select) {
   var form = select.form;
   var selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;

   if (selectedIndex === 1) {
     alert('test');
    form.method="get";

  }
```

}

when i select the google from the down list, why it can't alert a box and the method can't change to the get. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `onchange="selectSearch(select)"` to `onchange="selectSearch(this)"` and put the `select` in the `form` tag

Comment: This works for me, assuming you added that closing curly bracket to your Javascript function. Use a tool like Mozilla Firefox's Error Console to help you debug Javascript errors.

Comment: this is my site the search box locates on the right top of the page.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming you added the closing curly bracket. This should work.

Comment: this is my site,http://phplist.xxmn.com/ the search box locates at the right top of the page. could you give the Mozilla Firefox's Error Console to test it. thank you

Comment: i put the function on the firebu's js console, when select the google search. it still can't alert a box.

Comment: In your site, you are using `this.value` instead of `this` as I told you to do so.

Comment: i am sorry, i have changed to this. it still can't work. thank you

Comment: I just tested your site using FX 3.6.15 and IE 8 and both executed the "tset" alert

Comment: yeah. i got it. thank you.but when i click the alert then see the html source code. the form method still post, why it wasn't change to the get.

Comment: That is because the `select` is outside the `form` tag

Comment: i have put a test page to this url phplist.xxmn.com/1.html  and put the select in form tag, but the method still be not changed.

Comment: The function is working just fine as expected. It is doing exactly what it meant to do. If you want to add even more functionality, then this is subject to another question. But this one was answered already.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="search_l" onchange="selectSearch(select)">
```

What is happening here? You're passing in `select` to the Javascript function, but this value is not defined.

Also, your Javascript code is missing a closing curly bracket.

Comment: `function selectSearch(select) {
   var form = select.form;
   var selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;

   if (selectedIndex === 1) {
     alert('test');
    form.method="get";

  }
}`

Comment: i have added the lost curly,but it still can't work.this is my site phplist.xxmn.com the search box locates at the right top of the page.

Comment: but when i click the alert then see the html source code. the form method still post, why it wasn't change to the get. thank you.